# I want to change my shortcut settings in IntellijIdea

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I have an xml file that defines the shortcut and i have copied it to .intellijidea>config>keymaps and then opened my IntellijIdea and in settings tab i have selected my xml file but the problem is that some shortcuts defined in that file are not working ..
Any ideas ??

Answer (score 0):

May be you have some applications that catch your shortcuts in 'global' scope ?

Comment: Yeah may be .. but i just deleted the file again and did the same procedure above and it worked.. So dont really know what went wrong the first time ..